# Protocol and Delegate model function is called, but does not run

Tags: ios, swift, function, delegates, protocols

Hello I am having some trouble getting a function to run when called by the delegate in another view controller.  I have two view controllers.  The goal is, when one of the view controllers is closed, it will call a function.

Here is the code for the first view controller.  the "A" and "B" print in the debug consul.

```
protocol UpdateApproachProtocol {
    func addApproachToEntry()
}

class ApproachViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var delegate: UpdateApproachProtocol?
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Add an Approach"
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        safeArea = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        setupView()
        
       
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        LoadData.shared.approachArray.append(newApproach)
        print("A")
        delegate?.addApproachToEntry()
        print("B")
    }
   
}
```

Here is the code for the other view controller... the "test" is never printed. What am I missing?

```
class AddEntryViewController: KeyboardViewController, SendTailToEntryProtocol  {
    
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let approachVC = ApproachViewController()
        approachVC.delegate = self
}
extension AddEntryViewController: UpdateApproachProtocol {
    func addApproachToEntry() {
        print("test")
       
    }
}
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
        if indexPath.section == 5 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            
            self.navigationController?.showDetailViewController(ApproachViewController(), sender: nil)
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Om `viewDidLoad` in your second code sample, you create an `ApproachViewController` and then never do anything with it -- it immediately goes out of scope. Are you missing showing us some code? Or is this not actually the `ApproachViewController` instance that is being shown?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `ApproachViewController` going out of scope? the only reason I called this is to set the delegate equal to the View Controller.  There is some code missing, mostly just formatting for my UIPickerView.

Comment: Yes - you create the view controller, and then you don't do anything with it. It never gets presented to the screen. You set the delegate on it, but that's inconsequential because the user never interacts with *that instance* of the view controller. I'm assuming that you've presented that view controller somewhere else (you aren't showing us that code) and what you really want is to set the instance that's actually being shown to the users to the delegate. But, again, you haven't shown enough code to say how that should happen.

Comment: Instead of posting code here in the comments (which is really hard to read), please edit your original question. Show where `ApproachViewController` is created and where `AddEntryViewController` is created

Comment: Updated.  on `AddEntryViewController` you can see when `ApproachViewController` is put onto the screen. and how it is closed and taken back to `AddEntryViewController `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code where you create `ApproachViewController`:

```
let approachVC = ApproachViewController()
approachVC.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.showDetailViewController(approachVC, sender: nil)
```

Then, remove this from `viewDidLoad`, since it just creates `ApproachViewController` and does nothing with it:

```
let approachVC = ApproachViewController()
approachVC.delegate = self
```